# How to return a the index.html.erb in the js.html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller like so:

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.js {render :layout => false}
    end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
hello i"m index.html.erb
```

**index.js.erb**

```
<%= render :template => "dashboard/index" %>
```

What I want to do is have index.html or index.js return the same thing. But I can't see to do that without making index.html.erb a partial (_index.html.erb) but then when a user makes an html call that won't work.

How can I get the index.js.erb to render index.html.erb? which I would then escape with jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= raw render(:template => "dashboard/index").to_json %>
```

Comment: It's basically just doing what you want: converting an html view into js.

Answer (score 1):

I have this code in my application to do it:

```
<%= escape_javascript(render :file => "/posts/index.html.erb") %>
```

No sure if it's a "right" way, but it definitely works.