# Use AJAX but still allow $(document).ready in Rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following files:

```
layouts/application.html.erb

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <%= flash_messages %>
  <%= yield %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').each(function(idx, elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        $elem.select2();
      });

      <%= yield :document_ready %>
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

This is the index.html.erb:

```
user_transactions/index.html.erb

<% content_for :document_ready do %>
<% render :partial => 'shared/datepicker' %>
<% end %>
<h3><%= I18n.translate("user_transaction.add") %></h3>
...
```

Now I wanted to have a more fluid interface so I did this in the controller:

```
user_transactions_controller.erb
def index
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @user_transactions = @company.user_transactions.order("date DESC").all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout => false }
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user_transactions }
  end
end
```

And created the following file:

```
user_transactions/index.js.erb    
document.getElementById('dashboard-body').innerHTML = 
  '<%= escape_javascript(render(:file => "user_transactions/index.html.erb")) %>'
```

I call the page with the :remote => true option.  I don't know if it's good but it works, I found this technique here: [How to return a the index.html.erb in the js.html.erb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260418/how-to-return-a-the-index-html-erb-in-the-js-html-erb-file)

However one problem I am facing is that none of the javascript code is working anymore.  There is the select2 (in the layout) that needs to run but also the part that is declared in the view index.html.erb itself (datepicker).

How can I keep the javascript but also keep the ajax and fast interface?

Comment: I'm wondering if ERB doesn't like `<script>` tags being outside of the `<head>`?

Comment: Are there errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: @IanAtkin ERB is simply text with ruby tags in it. In this case, that text just happens to be formatted like HTML. ERB doesn't care about the structure of your HTML at all. In fact it happily lets you flubb it all up completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

The JavaScript was present in the document because I'm calling it from the page that uses the application layout.  However it does not call the document.ready and even more, the events are unbinded once document.ready is called (thus the first time).

To keep the solution DRY I solved it like this:

I created partials for every javascript function that I need to in the document.ready part to be executed.  I changed the layouts/application.html.erb file to use those partials (or at least those that I want on every form) and in the  user_transactions/index.js.erb I call the partials that I need.

So I added this part in the index.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  <%= render(:partial => "shared/select2") %>
  <%= render(:partial => "shared/datepicker") %>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two bad guesses and a couple of questions:

When you call the page with :remote => true, have you verified that your JS is present on the page? And, where exactly are you calling the page from?

I suspect that your script may not be on the page because you've specified a false layout so nothing in the application.html.erb file will be available unless you're calling it from a page that uses the application layout.

I also think part of what's happening is when you render the `innerHTML`, you pull in all the code, but the JS doesn't actually get executed again so the script in `document.ready` isn't aware of the new stuff you added to the page. You'll have to call the JS again after setting the `innerHTML`.

You could wrap your `.each` in a function and call it once on `document.ready` and again after you populate your `innerHTML`.

Here's a similar question with a better explanation: [Rails Ajax: .js.erb rendered as text, not JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311247/rails-ajax-js-erb-rendered-as-text-not-js)

I hope I'm on the right track.

Comment: Yes JS is present on the page because I'm indeed calling it from a page that uses the application layout. Indeed the JS isn't being called anymore.